# c++ segmentation fault (core dumped) with modulus

Tags: c++

I am working on a program that allows the user to practice division. My code is below:

```
//div1
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define CLS "\033[2J\033[1;1H"
#define NEWLINE "\n"

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a, div1, div2;
    div1=rand()%11;
    div2=rand()%11;
    while (div2>div1) {
        swap(div1,div2);
        continue;
    }
    if (div1%div2!=0) {
        return main();
    } else {
        cout << CLS;
        cout << NEWLINE;
        do {
            cout << div1 << " / " << div2 << " = ?" << endl;
            cin >> a;
            cout << CLS;
            cout << NEWLINE;
            cout << "\t\tWrong!!" << endl;
            cout << NEWLINE;
        } while (a!=div1/div2);
        cout << CLS;
        cout << NEWLINE;
        cout << "\t\tCorrect!!" << endl;
        cout << NEWLINE;
        cout << "Hit enter to continue." << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
        return main();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, what it is supposed to do is first choose two random numbers. Then, it is supposed to check to see if the second number (div2) is greater than the first (div1), and if they are, it will switch them. Then, it will use the modulus (div1%div2) to make sure that the two numbers can be divided by each other without a remainder. If they cannot be divided without a remainder, it will restart the program (return main();). However, whenever I run it, I get the **segmentation fault: core dumped**, either when I start it or after running it a few times. Any ideas on how to fix this?


Thanks!!

Comment: `return main();` please don't do that.

Comment: What should I use then? system() calls?

Comment: return main() is basically a recursive call to main again and that will get you stuck in an infinite loop, which will eventually overflow the stack. Hence, the segmentation fault. Your program needs to either end or loop continuously, but normally (not through a recursive call as that will overflow your stack) depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: All right, I can dump the return main(). But what should I use to re-start the program, if the part with the modulus (div1%div2!=0) fails?

Comment: Rather than restarting the program, use a while(true) and write your program so it can just loop continuously without calling itself again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what I've said in the comments. Obviously, you can refactor this so that it works more gracefully (as of now it'll give you floating point exceptions sometimes), but it gives you an idea on how to do this without calling main again.

NOTE: You do not need to make a constant for NEWLINE. There is already a built-in constant in std. In fact, you're already using that constant (endl). So you can just do cout << endl instead of cout << NEWLINE.

```
    //div1
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#define CLS "\033[2J\033[1;1H"
#define NEWLINE "\n"

int main() {
    while(true) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int a, div1, div2;
        div1=rand()%11;
        div2=rand()%11;
        while (div2>div1) {
            swap(div1,div2);
            continue;
        }
        if (div1%div2!=0) {
        } else {
            cout << CLS;
            cout << NEWLINE;
            do {
                cout << div1 << " / " << div2 << " = ?" << endl;
                cin >> a;
                cout << CLS;
                cout << NEWLINE;
                cout << "\t\tWrong!!" << endl;
                cout << NEWLINE;
            } while (a!=div1/div2);
            cout << CLS;
            cout << NEWLINE;
            cout << "\t\tCorrect!!" << endl;
            cout << NEWLINE;
            cout << "Hit enter to continue." << endl;
            cin.ignore();
            cin.get();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did something a tad different, but it has the same general idea, and it seemed to work. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

This code can get into "divide by 0" error. This is why you would be getting error.

The line "if (div1%div2!=0) {"   seems erroneous.
In this line if div2 == 0, then your code will crash.

Comment: That is incorrect. Dividing by zero is indeed undefined, but it will not cause a crash. You can test this out easily. Write a program that divides by 0. The compiler will warn you when you compile it, but it will not crash when you actually run it. The warning will look something like this: `test.cpp:12:10: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]`

Comment: @EdwardL. As per my understanding, when you run program with divide by zero, you will get SIGFPE error and the program does terminate.

Comment: I suppose it may be compiler/system specific. I tested this under clang-600.0.57 and it does not crash when compiled with this version, I'll try to validate to see what the GNU compiler will do.

Comment: It appears that the GNU compiler behaves slightly differently and will terminate unlike the Clang compiler. Both will emit warnings during compilation, however. Regardless, it is NOT the cause of his segmentation fault. That is caused by the recursive call to main().